# Python3: comparing dynamic list to create a regexp

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am currently writing a class to create a regexp. 
As an input, we got 3 sentences in a list ("textContent") and the output regexp should match the 3 sentences.

For this, I use ZIP. The code below is 100% working.

```
from array import *

textContent = []

textContent.append("The sun is.shining")
textContent.append("the Sun is ShininG")
textContent.append("the_sun_is_shining")

s = ""

for x, y, z in zip(textContent[0], textContent[1], textContent[2]):
    if x == y == z:
        s+=str(x)
    else:
        s+="."

#answer is ".he..un.is..hinin."
print(s)
```

It's working but ONLY with 3 sentences in a List.

Now, I want the same comparison but with a dynamic list that could contain 2 or 256 sentences for example. And I'm stuck. I don't know how to adjust the code for that.

I noticed that the following throws no error:

`zip(*textContent)`

So, I'm stuck with the variables that I compare before: x, y, z

```
for x, y, z in zip(*textContent):
```

It could work only if textContent contains 3 values...

Any idea? May be another class than ZIP could make the job.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem with zipping and comparing:

```py
l = ['asd', 'agd', 'add', 'abd']

for letters in list(zip(*l)):
    if all([letters[0] == letter for letter in letters]):
        print('Yey')
    else:
        print('Ugh')

>>> Yey
>>> Ugh
>>> Yey
```

And for l = ['asd', 'agg', 'add', 'cbb'] it will print 3 'Ugh'.
Also you should check if l is longer than 0

Comment: Have I correctly understood your question? Do you understand my solution?

Comment: Thank you! It's working great. I'm not familiar with this but I will google it: if all([letters[0] == letter for letter in letters])

Comment: to all() you can provide a list o booleans and it evaluates id all of them is true. And this [x for x in y] syntax is called list comprehension